# Gems dependency error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am following Michael Hartl's Tutorial on RoR. During the 3rd Chapter (sample_app), I am trying to install the gems via the "bundle install --without production command" but I keep encountering the following issue:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.3) ruby depends on
      railties (= 3.2.3) ruby

    jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (3.2.4.rc1)
```

On using the terminal to install jquery-rail, i.e. "gem install jquery-rails -v '2.0.0'", I get successfully installed. But after I do "bundle install", the same dependency issue crops up.

Another thing, my local gem file shows that I do have "railties -v 3.2.3", so why the error showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify the version numbers in your gemfile? (For future reference, pasting the lines from the gemfile would help us solve the problem.)

Try either removing the version numbers in the gemfile for jquery-rails or using ~> like so:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
```

FWIW, it all works fine on my machine with those same versions, except jquery-rails is 2.0.1.

Comment: source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

Comment: The above is my Gemfile. As you can see, I have mentioned specific versions of all gems. Thanks so much